# Retrieve URI of an XML DOM object using Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, dom

In Firefox and Chrome the `documentURI` property of the document node object of an XML DOM will return the URI of the DOM if it is created using the `XMLHTTPRequest` object.

Is there an equivalent property for the Internet Explorer DOM, and if so what is it? The `documentURI`, `url`, `URL` and `baseURI` properties all return either null or undefined.

The [MSXML documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms767669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the *`url`* property made me hope that this would return the URL used in the HTTP request that created the DOM - but the example given doesn't use `XMLHTTPRequest`.

The code I've used to create the DOM and then test the property is below:

```
function getXslDom(url) {
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest == "undefined") {
        XMLHttpRequest = function () {
            return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
        };
    }
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, false);
    req.send(null);
    var status = req.status;
    if (status == 200 || status == 0) {
        return req.responseXML;
    } else {
        throw "HTTP request for " + url + " failed with status code: " + status;
    }
};
var xslDom = getXslDom('help.xsl');
// the following shows "undefined" for IE
window.alert(xslDom.documentURI);
```

Comment: The given example on MSDN didn't use XMLHttpRequest, but would it be an option to use the alternative method(DOMDocument->load)?

Comment: @Dr.Molle Unfortunately this has to use XMLHttpRequest. This is for the JavaScript API of a browser-based XSLT 2.0 processor - so the DOM object is most likely to come from an AJAX-style request, but we don't actually have control over how the DOM is created - as this is on the other side of the interface.

Comment: Have you tried `.URLUnencoded`? Sorry I don't have IE to test it for you. It's `undefined` in most browsers except IE.

Comment: I've just tested it, didn't work with `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: @Adnan thanks for testing this, I hadn't tried it myself - hopefully its something similar - the documentation doesn't seem too clear

Comment: So what is it exactly that you're trying to achieve, maybe we can come up with some way to do it

Comment: @Adnan The JS API for an XSLT2.0 processor (implemented in JS) supports the function, importStylesheet(dom),  the base-URI of the dom object (which will most likely be the result of an XMLHTTPRequest) is required for resolving relative URIs for xsl:import/xsl:include etc. Within the XSLT. The API has other methods that accept just the URI of the stylsheet but users want the option to use this function and the dom object also

Comment: Did you debug your getXlsDom function to see if it's returning ok or throwing an exception? PS: I edited your javascript code for better identation.

Comment: What about updating the responseXML object before returning it? IOW, `var dom = req.responseXML; dom.documentURI = dom.documentURI | url`

Comment: @FlavioCysne thanks for the indentation - I did test the output of getXslDom() with IE - I probably should have shown this test in the sample with hindsight

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan dom.documentURI is readonly - also, as this is for an API, we can't really expect users to do this kind of thing anyway. We may need to extend the API functions to accept a URI as well as the DOM object, but this is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example from the MSXML page you linked I managed to get it to work:

```
<script>

  var getXslDom = function(url) {
    if(typeof ActiveXObject === 'function') {
      var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
      xmlDoc.async = false;
      xmlDoc.load(url);
      if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
         var myErr = xmlDoc.parseError;
         throw "You have error " + myErr.reason;
      } else {
         return xmlDoc;
      }
    } else {
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", url, false);
        req.send(null);
        var status = req.status;
        if (status == 200 || status == 0) {
            return req.responseXML;
        } else {
            throw "HTTP request for " + url + " failed with status code: " + status;
        }
    }
  }

  var dom = getXslDom('help.xsl')
  alert(dom.documentURI || dom.url)

</script>
```

Here is [a demo](http://bijtel.com/stackoverflow/xsl/).

Cheers!

*PS:* I used "alert" only because the OP seems to use it, personally I prefer "console.log", which I also recommend to the OP.

Comment: What you're doing here is creating the DOM in another way (similar to that in the example I linked to) to show that in some circumstances dom.url can work. I'm hoping for a more universal solution because our code the retrieves the URI from the DOM is on the other side of an API - we can't control how the DOM is created. On console.log: Our finished solution exploits Log4J style logging with different LogHandlers and LogFormatters optimised for various browsers and plugins - 'alert()' was just to simplify things here

Comment: Make sure the content type is text/xml. If you can not control the content type there is no way to make this work without parsing the XML manually for IE.

Comment: Yes, we can't control the content type from the HTTP request as it is on the other side of the API - but it is reasonable to assume that it will be text/xml. If IE doesn't provide a method to access the DOM URI in the case I outlined (looking increasingly likely) then this isn't consistent with other browsers which is unfortunate